# Not able delete to node 'parameter' of xml file

Tags: java, xml, removechild

```
- <deviceparameters>
- <parameter componenttype="Table">
       <name>TPCSEC</name> 
       <oid>342234</oid> 
       <writable>true</writable> 
       <description>Tata Power SED</description> 
     - <columns>
           <colname access="ReadOnly" type="Integer">col1</colname> 
           <colname access="ReadOnly" type="Integer">col2</colname> 
       </columns>
     - <rows>
           <value>123</value> 
          <value>231</value> 
      </rows>
  </parameter>
- <parameter componenttype="ListBox">
      <name>Enum</name> 
      <oid>7892</oid> 
      <writable>true</writable> 
      <description>This is Enumeration</description> 
    - <paramvalues type="String">
         <value default="Yes">1231</value> 
         <value default="No">3423</value> 
         <value default="Yes">231</value> 
      </paramvalues>
  </parameter>
  </deviceparameters>
```

This my XML file. Now I want to delete the node '`parameter`' having name `TPCSEC`.

For this deletion I am using below code.

```
               DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = dBuilder.parse(selectedFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");

                System.out.println(""+nList.getLength());
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
                {
                    Node nNode =  nList.item(temp);    
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String upname1 = getTagValue("name", eElement);                                

                    if(upname1.equals(nodeName))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Parent:   "+nNode.getParentNode().getNodeName());
                        System.out.println("nodename: "+nNode.getNodeName());
                        System.out.println("rmoving ....");

                        rootElement.removeChild(eElement);
                        System.out.println("removed...");

                    }
                }
```

Is my code is correct. While executing, it does not show any error or warning. But it does not delete the requested node. 
Thanks..

Comment: what does the program output when you run it?

Comment: it executes all the statement. till 'removed...'

Comment: @MK This is my output Parent: deviceparameters nodename: parameter rmoving .... removed...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867958/remove-a-child-of-root-of-xml-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you written it to the original xml file. I mean

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();   
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);   
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(selectedFile); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see one issue within your code. That is removing items as you iterate through the loop.

So Here is an example.

You have a list of 10 things, at index 5, you remove, you increment your position, now you are at index 6, but within your list, you are looking at item at index 7.

I tend to reverse the loop, set temp = nList.getLength(), and do temp--, to insure you are not removing items before you get to them.

Comment: No, the nodelist will not be changing as he removes things.

Comment: is it necessary to delete all child nodes of node before deleting it...??

Comment: @Sachin no, you can remove nodes with children.

Comment: @Sachin, No. my example means you are deleting in reverse order, If you delete something that you already visited in a list, it doesn't matter if you remove it from the list, because you do not need to visit that index again.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing rootElement.removeChild(eElement) but eElement is not necessarily a child of root, it could be a child of another node in the tree, because you are getting *all* the "property" nodes.  I think you want to do

```
eElement.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
```

Comment: Yes he would, nList is a list containing pointer to the objects. Since he is removing the element, he is essentially removing the item from the list.

Comment: You are commenting in the wrong answer.  NodeList will be a list references to nodes found in the tree.  As you remove these nodes from the tree, the list of found nodes will not be changing.