# Remove a child of root of XML using java

Tags: java, xml, removechild

This is my xml file.

```
- <deviceparameters>
       - <parameter componenttype="TextBox">
         <name>Operating Type</name> 
         <oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.31163.5.1.1</oid>  
         <writable>true</writable> 
         <description>The operating type defines which waveform type is used. This configuration takes several seconds to execute</description> 
       - <paramvalues type="Integer">
            <value default="No">123</value> 
         </paramvalues>
         </parameter>

       - <parameter componenttype="TextBox">
         <name>Active Waveform Status</name> 
         <oid>1.3.6.1.4.1.31163.5.1.2</oid> 
         <writable>false</writable> 
         <description>Show the status of the waveform configured by operatingType</description> 
       - <paramvalues type="String">
            <value default="yes">Active</value> 
      </paramvalues>
      </parameter>
    </deviceparameters>
```

I want to remove node with name '`Active wavwform Status`'. How can I reomve that particular node from xml.

The code I have written is below.

```
rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
String nodeName = TF_name.getText();


System.out.println(""+nList.getLength());

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength();temp++)                
{
    Node nNode =  nList.item(temp);    
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    String upname1 = getTagValue("name", eElement);

    if(upname1.equals(nodeName))
    {
        System.out.println("Parent:   "+nNode.getParentNode().getNodeName());
        System.out.println("nodename: "+nNode.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("rmoving ....");

        rootElement.removeChild(nNode);

        System.out.println("removed..."); 
    }                   
}
```

Comment: And did you get any errors? Does it not work?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? There's some magic in the `getTagValue` method and we don't know the value of `TF_name`...

Comment: getTagValue() method returns the tag value of node. And TF_name is textfield where user will enter name to delete node.

Comment: @Thilo I am not getting any errors. It is executing completly, but it is not deleting that node.

Comment: Is it printing the message on `System.out` that you have inserted about `"rmoving ...."`, &c.?

Comment: Those hyphens - in the XML... did you cut and paste via internet explorer? or are they actually in the file??

Comment: are u saying about hypens before nodes ie. -<deviceparameters> ? Those were there in my xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
Actually I was deleting the node from my xml file, but I was not writing it to my xml file.
I was missing following part

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();   
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);   
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(selectedFile); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

After long time study of code I found this silly mistake, so I corrected it.
 Anyways thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove node using DocumentTraversal,NodeIterator.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/file.xml");           
DocumentTraversal traversal = (DocumentTraversal) doc;
Node a = doc.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println("Current File Content");
NodeIterator iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
Element b = null;
for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
    Element e = (Element) n;                
    if ("parameter".equals(e.getTagName())) {
        System.out.println(""+e.getTagName() +" "+ e.getTextContent());
        b = e;
    } else if ("name".equals(e.getTagName()) && "Active Waveform Status".equals(e.getTextContent()) && b != null) {
        b.removeChild(e);
    }
}
```

To write new content into file

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/riddhish/developerworkspace/SplitString/src/com/updatexmlwithjava/file.xml"));
            iterator = traversal.createNodeIterator(a, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, true);
            b = null;
            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("deviceparameters");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            for (Node n = iterator.nextNode(); n != null; n = iterator.nextNode()) {
                Element e = (Element) n;                 

                rootElement.appendChild(doc.importNode(n, true));

            }
            transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: did you have check your console output?

Comment: Active Waveform Status         Chield node length =17 parameter Operating Type 1.3.6.1.4.1.31163.5.1.1 true The operating type defines which waveform type is used. This configuration takes several seconds to execute 123 parameter Active Waveform Status 1.3.6.1.4.1.31163.5.1.2 false Show the status of the waveform configured by operatingType Active

Comment: @SachinMhetre i have edit my answer, just you have to replace a.removeChild(b); to b.removeChild(e);

Comment: In Chat room,i have written xml, java code and console output it working fine, see once

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion on how to remove a node, including printing. You must be in the correct context, if the node to be removed isn't attached to the root you cannot remove it, as you are trying. Find the node, get its parent and remove it from the parent. The removeNode method is the important part:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RemoveNodestuff
{
    Document doc;

    public RemoveNodestuff(String filename) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(new File(filename));
        print(doc.getDocumentElement());
    }

    public void removeNode(String tagName, String value)
    {
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if (nl != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element item = (Element) nl.item(i);
                if (item.getTextContent().equals(value))
                {
                    item.getParentNode().removeChild(item);
                }
            }
        }
        print(doc.getDocumentElement());
    }

    private void print(Node n)
    {
        NodeList nl = n.getChildNodes();
        if (nl != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node item = nl.item(i);
                if (item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    System.out.println(item.getNodeName() + "  " + item.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    if (item.hasChildNodes())
                    {
                        print(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException
    {
        RemoveNodestuff removeNodestuff = new RemoveNodestuff(
                args[0]);
        removeNodestuff.removeNode("name", "Active Waveform Status");
    }
}
```